# Is there a way to prevent gatsby to fetch remote api each time develop command is launched?

Tags: gatsby

On a gatsbyjs application with the `gatsby-source-wordpress` plugin, the remote data from Wordpress API are fetched each time the command `gatsby develop` is launched. Is there a way to keep cache as the fetching process can take several minutes ?

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby already caches datas. Caches is flushed when gatsby-config.js or gatsby-node.js files are changed.